# Can I make animated summaries of shows/movies?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I was wondering if I could make animated short videos (like a minute long). I was planning to make short animations doing a very basic version of the stories, they would include all of my own sounds and images but they would still be summaries of those shows or movies, is that fair use?

Comment: It's very hard to answer generally. A lot would depend on what you are copying. You run the risk of infringement on trademarked names and characters, or of fooling people into thinking they were buying/streaming a genuine licenced product. If you include any distinctive material such as quotes or unique story elements, you might be done for breach of copyright (but if the story elements are very generic or based on fact you might be OK). You might be able to claim your work is parody, or intended for educational purposes, but it would depend on the jurisdiction.